# Regular expression to parse log.

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to write a regular expression to parse out an old IRC log that I have.

Regular Expression:

```
  (\d\d:\d\d)(<)(@|\+)(.+?)>(.*)
```

LOG Example:

```
= 00:00<@billy> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
= 00:03<+tom> text text text text text text 
= 00:03<somedude> text text
```

I've been able to parse out everything that I need from the log except for users that do not have operator(@) or voice(+) status in the channel.

Thus, when I run the regex I get the following:

```
[('00:00', '<', '@', 'bill', " text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text ")]
[('00:00', '<', '+', 'tom', " text text text text text text ]
[]
```

Hence, 'somedude' is missing. Would anyone have any hints on how to better approach this?

Comment: Make that group optional by adding `?`. `(\d\d:\d\d)(<)([@+]?)(.+?)>(.*)`. See https://regex101.com/r/XJESLT/1. Well, I guess some groups are redudant here, feel free to re-vamp the pattern as per your needs.

Comment: Look, maybe [`(\d{2}:\d{2})<([@+]?[^>]*)>(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/XJESLT/2) is better? (`[^>]` may match a newline though, `[^>\n]*` might be better than)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew none of the suggestions worked for me. I'm using Python 3.0 with `re` if that helps.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that was a typing error on my part. It works great now. Thank you.

Comment: I posted an answer based on my second suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point is to make `@` or `+` optional by adding `?` after `(@|\+)`, or - better - `[@+]` => `[@+]?`. Note you do not need to escape `+` in the character class as it matches a literal plus symbol inside the class.

In Python 3, I suggest using the regex with named capturing groups.

```
import re
ss = [ '= 00:00<@billy> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text ',
'= 00:03<+tom> text text text text text text ',
'= 00:03<somedude> text text']
for s in ss:
    m = re.search(r'(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2})<(?P<user>[@+]?[^>]*)>(?P<message>.*)', s)
    if m:
        print(m.groupdict())
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/VYtizC), output:

```
{'time': '00:00', 'message': ' text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text ', 'user': '@billy'}
{'time': '00:03', 'message': ' text text text text text text ', 'user': '+tom'}
{'time': '00:03', 'message': ' text text', 'user': 'somedude'}
```

**Pattern details**

- `(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2})` - Group "time": 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits
- `<` - a `<`
- `(?P<user>[@+]?[^>]*)` - Group "user": 1 or 0 `@` or `+`, and then any 0+ chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>`
- `(?P<message>.*)` - Group "message": any 0+ chars, up to the end of the line